# Which one sounds right: "life is short" or "lives are short"?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, singular-vs-plural

According to the [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/life_1?q=life), "life" can be a countable and uncountable noun.

> *The floods caused a massive loss of life*
>   *Hundreds of lives were threatened*

But if we wanted to say "life" in general, which one sounds right or are they both grammatically correct?

1. **life is short**
   or
2. **lives are short**.

Comment: "Life is short" sounds more natural since the word is being used as an abstract noun. "Lives are short" sounds wrong, What lives are being referred to? "Our lives are short" makes more sense.

Comment: Neither sound wrong, exactly. But "life is short" is a very common phrase in American English, and is probably better suited to your purpose.

Comment: @MickSharpe, plural countable noun expresses things in general. Ex, "Books are good" (any book or all books are good.

Comment: I wouldn't say either of them. Whose life? And of uncountable, how can you uniformly quantify all lives. I guess we need to learn done statistics and incorporate that into our mindframe. Thank you, for your thought.

Comment: This is not opinion based. There is a demonstrable difference between talking about 'life'  as a concept *(mass noun)* and talking about plural instances of the *count noun* 'life', as   the concept of life  'instantiated' in individual lives. Cf my answer.

Comment: The answer, truth be known, is found in the dictionary page cited by the OP. Scroll down, scroll down!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To talk about *life* in general, *life* is considered a mass noun. That is to say, to talk about *life as a concept*, we say *life in general*; *In general*, life is short. This very usage is what makes *life* here a mass noun. Compare *Death is inevitable.*

However, we can also talk about  *lives in general*. This talks about multiple instances of the singlular count noun *life*. For instance, we  might  say, *In war, lives are cheap*. Here the stress is on individual lives.  But you could also *In war, life is cheap*, with *life* as a concept.

You could also say, *in general, deaths are inevitable, in the medical profession*

For 'types' of mass nouns, see [this resource by the University of Washington](https://staff.washington.edu/marynell/grammar/noncount.html).

Comment: But *physics* is an uncountable noun, I think?

Comment: @DamkerngT Okay, I will give that to you for this usage (see included link). But it, like just about any noun, can be used as a count noun.

Comment: But in dictionary, life can be count & uncount noun.

Comment: Yes @Tom but I'm giving you the answer as to which version is better if you are taking about life in general. Note my previous sentence; I did not say *lives in general*.

Comment: Of course, either version could be correct. As usual it depends on the context and the speaker's intent. A physician may very prefer to say *lives are short*. The best answer to your question is that we need more context; but in the ***most general way***,  the answer is *life is short*.

Comment: @DamkerngT A thought question for you: since physics and math(ematic)s are usually used as mass nouns, why then are they often given as examples of *singular nouns* that end in *-s*? Mass nouns don't have singular   forms!

Comment: @AlanCarmack I really have no idea (this is the first time I've heard that they're often used as examples of *-s* singular nouns). Maybe because it's a common mistake or something. I don't know. If it's so, I'd guess that they use the term "singular nouns" loosely, to emphasize that these nouns are used with singular verbs, perhaps.

Comment: @DamkerngT The  ELU post [What is the difference between a "singular noun" and a "plural noun treated as singular"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4656/what-is-the-difference-between-a-singular-noun-and-a-plural-noun-treated-as-s) throws "a physic" into the issue.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Uncountable nouns use the singular form. If you want to debate whether or not they are really "singular" in the same sense that a countable noun can be, okay, but that's more a philosophical discussion. Grammatically, they are treated as singular. We say, "Physics is a fascinating subject", NOT "Physics are fascinating subjects", etc. One could imagine a language where uncountable nouns have their own grammatical number that is neither singular nor plural, but that's not how English works. (Though I've got to remember that if I'm ever asked to invent a new language.)

Comment: @Jay, are  you saying *physics* is a mass noun? Or that it is a plural form used with singular meaning? At any rate, [as Fowler, for one, has  shown](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/4984/166321) the issue is not that straightforward. Ethics is a subject one can study, but one can say that someone's ethics are terrible. Apparently, the same goes for mathematics, (and also for physics?)