# life or lives or any?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

*My husband and I live **an active life/active lives**.*

What is the correct way? I might be wrong but I think I’ve come across both variations of this kind. Can both options be used in a sentence like this?

Comment: The answer to this question might be helpful: [Which one sounds right: “life is short” or “lives are short”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/104392/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both are possible.

If you say

> We live an active **life**.

Then you put the emphasis slightly on your *common* life, you might be active *together* or have an active lifestyle in your household.

On the other hand, if you choose

> We live active **lives**.

Then you are more focused on your *individual* lifestyle. You emphasize that *each one of you* is active.

But note that it’s just the focus of the speaker, the singular form does not exclude that each of you does his or her individual activities and the plural still works if you are active together.